# Is Bluetooth Smart Ready low energy?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I searched on bluetooth.com , bluetooth.org but I didn't find any explanation about Bluetooth Smart Ready Device being low energy.

I know Bluetooth Smart Ready is dual mode. (Backward compatible)

My question is When Bluetooth Smart Ready is connected to older Bluetooth device, is it still in low energy mode or does it require more power(like older Bluetooth Devices) ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the best place for this.  SuperUser might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no it is not in low energy mode because it is not using the low energy subset of Bluetooth v4.0.

Long answer: Bluetooth v4.0 defines two types of transceivers:

- Dual-Mode Devices (aka Smart Ready Devices): Dual mode devices include all the features of standard Bluetooth v4.0 (Classic Bluetooth + Bluetooth High Speed + Bluetooth Low Energy); BLE functionality is integrated into the existing Bluetooth controller. Dual mode devices, such as PCs and Mobile phones, can utilize the full package versions of the technology running side by side.
- Single-mode Devices (aka Bluetooth Smart): single mode devices
  implement the low energy protocol stack only. The single mode devices
  benefit from the low power consumption and low cost of implementation
  provided by v4.0. Therefore, the devices are cheaper and consume
  less power than dual mode devices.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Smart means Bluetooth 4.0. The only common in Bluetooth Smart and the older versions is the frequency range.The communications is vastly different, requiring different radio hardware too.

So if a device is dual mode, it can either use the low energy, or the standard communication. And because of this, in standard mode, the energy consumption is the same as with the standard devices.

Answer (score 0):

No, When a backwards compatible Dual Mode/Smart Ready device is connecting and transmitting on Bluetooth 2.1, 3.0 or EDR it is not Low Energy.

What makes low energy low energy is the short burst transmissions, packet size and the way the processing works. Being Dual Mode / Smart Ready just combines the necessary chips and antenna into one package for ease of manufacturing and design.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Smart Ready = Dual Mode, i.e. it can switch between BR/EDR (Classic) and BLE.

For BLE, it is first and foremost the protocol that makes it "low energy", i.e. low consumption.

So, when the Smart Ready device works in BLE mode, it is low energy. When it works in Classic mode, it is not low energy.